# Case statement issue in Erlang when working with n2o framework

Tags: erlang, case, n2o

Question about the case statement in Erlang.

I am using n2o as my web application framework.

In my sign in page i created an event to extract fields from the page when a user clicks the sign up button,

```
event(sign_up) - >

Gender = {Male,Female} = {wf:q(gm),wf:q(gf)},

Result = case Gender of 
    Gender when Male == true -> <<"M">>;
    Gender when Female == true -> <<"F">>;
    Gender when Male == false, Female == false -> <<"Not Selected">>
end,

error_logger:info_msg("Stuff",[{Result}]).
```

When I test the page, the logging code never gets hit. It only shows when i remove the case statement. Oddly, when executing the case statement in the shell, it evaluates correctly.

Am i missing something with my case statement?

Comment: Note to all: `wf:q/1` returns a **string**, not an atom (which would be plain wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tracing, i did not realize that these functions within the tuple were returning string literals rather than atom populated patterns i was using for matching in the case statement.

With that in mind the working solution:

```
event(sign_up) - >

Gender = {list_to_atom(wf:q(gm)),list_to_atom(wf:q(gf))},

Result = case Gender of 
    {true,false} -> <<"M">>;
    {false,true} -> <<"F">>;
    Gender -> <<"Not Selected">>;
end,
```

So the lesson learned is make sure the data types you match are the same.

It took a while :) but valuable lesson learned.

Answer (score 2):

To see something in the format, you need a place holder (here the ~p standing for pretty print) int the format string.
I also simplified the case statement.

```
event(sign_up) - >

Gender = {wf:q(gm),wf:q(gf)},

Result = case Gender of 
    {true,false} -> <<"M">>;
    {false,true} -> <<"F">>;
    {false,false} -> <<"Not Selected">>;
%[edit] check the type of the return value of wf:q/1 if different from boolean
    Gender -> Gender
end,

error_logger:info_msg("Gender selection : ~p~n",[Result]).
```

Comment: The code propose should work as expected, at one condition: wf:q(gm) and wf:q(gf) must return either true or false. I didn't check what could be the output of these function so if you are getting trouble, I suggest you to review the doc or, easier, to trace the result of the call as I propose in the edited code.

Answer (score 0):

As a side-note, `if` is also an interesting (shorter) structure in this case:

```
event(sign_up) - >
   {M,F}  = {wf:q(gm),wf:q(gf)},

   Result = if M =:= true -> <<"M">>;
               F =:= true -> <<"F">>;
               true       -> <<"Not Selected">> end,

   error_logger:info_msg("Gender selection : ~p\n",[Result]).
```

`=:=` (exactly equal to, compares **values and types**) is more precise then `==` (equal to, compares **values only**), so unless you want to compare only values, it's better to use the *exactly equal to* `=:=` operator (precise code is better !).

---

**Wrong Type. Use Lists, not atoms**

Reading the [documentation](http://nitrogenproject.com/doc/api.html), `wf:q/1` returns a string (aka list).

So none of this can work. You have to compare to lists to lists (don't convert a list to an atom. Never ever do that. It's wrong, unless you perfectly know what you do, and know **HOW** to do it right).

So, corrected example, using lists (in lowercase):

```
event(sign_up) - >
   {M,F}  = {wf:q(gm),wf:q(gf)},

   Result = if M =:= "true" -> <<"M">>;
               F =:= "true" -> <<"F">>;
               true         -> <<"Not Selected">> end,

   error_logger:info_msg("Gender selection : ~p\n",[Result]).
```

Comment: The log message now shows but when M or F is true, the result always  returns <<"Not Selected">>.

Comment: Are you sure `wf:q(gm)` returns an atom instead of a binary or list ? Check first.

Comment: Did that for you: `wf:q/1` returns a string (list).